# How to return List instead of an object using Lambda and EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, lambda

I have this code that returns a single user:

```
  return RetryWithExpression<User, User>(u => u.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserEmail == userEmail));
```

I am trying to convert it so that It returns many users like this:

```
return RetryWithExpression<User, List<User>>(u => u.Select(x => x.sUserCity == cityId));
```

This does not compile and I get an error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<bool>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<User>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

How do I return a List from this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `Where` which filters. `Select` does a projection. In your case `Select` would return an `IEnumerable<bool>`, hence the compilation error.

```
return RetryWithExpression<User, List<User>>(u => u.Where(x => x.sUserCity == cityId));
```

Since `RetryWithExpression` expects a list, call `ToList()`

```
return RetryWithExpression<User, List<User>>(u => u.Where(x => x.sUserCity == cityId).ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks but this dosen't fix the code. I still get an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<User>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<User>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)